# ¿Cómo redondear un JButton en Java?

Tags: java, java-swing, jbutton

Quiero poder redondear un **JButton** en Java. Pensé que sería fácil, pero aparentemente no lo es. Investigué y había una librería llamada *look and feel2* que resolvía el problema, pero nada.

Aquí dejo el código:

```java
iniciar_sesion.putClientProperty(
SubstanceLookAndFeel.BUTTON_SHAPER_PROPERTY, new
StandardButtonShaper().getButtonBorder(iniciar_sesion));

iniciar_sesion.putClientProperty( SubstanceLookAndFeel.BUTTON_SIDE_PROPERTY,
SubstanceConstants.Side.RIGHT);

iniciar_sesion.putClientProperty(
SubstanceLookAndFeel.BUTTON_OPEN_SIDE_PROPERTY,
SubstanceConstants.Side.LEFT);

iniciar_sesion.putClientProperty(
SubstanceLookAndFeel.BUTTON_OPEN_SIDE_PROPERTY,
SubstanceConstants.Side.TOP);

iniciar_sesion.putClientProperty(
    SubstanceLookAndFeel.BUTTON_OPEN_SIDE_PROPERTY, SubstanceConstants.Side.BOTTOM);
```

Comment: Para empezar ¿Que estas usando?¿Swing o javaFX?

Comment: estoy usando java Swing

Comment: La librería que estás tratando de usar se llama `Substance` es una de las cosas más personalizables que han surgido, desafortunadamente el desarrollador perdió su acceso a su cuenta en Java.net y al subir la siugiente versión fuera de java.net el código y la forma de usarlo habían cambiado demasiado y casi nadie hizo el esfuerzo de reaprenderlo.

Answer (score 2):

En las nuevas versiones de Swing ya no funcionan los trucos que se usaban en versiones anteriores como borde nulo

```
setBorder(null)
```

o el truco borde vacío

```
setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0,0,0,0));
```

esto debido a las rutinas que trae la apariencia por defecto mejor conocida como `Metal Look And Feel` han cambiado

Así que la opción es usar otro [Look And Feel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/index.html), te recomiendo usar el que se llama Nimbus, y que ha sido diseñado como sucesor de Metal.

Debes de cargarlo antes de mostrar tu frame o no notarás cambios, puedes hacerlo como en este ejemplo al inicar tu main.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo;

public class Roundbutton extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 34534511L;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            for (LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // If Nimbus is not available, you can set the GUI to another look and feel.
        }
        //       
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Rounded Button Example");
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.setSize(150, 150);


        JButton addBtn = new JButton("X");

        frame.add(addBtn);

        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

El ejemplo se ve así corriendo:

[image: boton con bordes redondeados con nimbus]

Answer (score 1):

Puedes crear una clase que implemente la interfaz **Border**.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

public class Roundbutton extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 34534511L;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //       
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Rounded Button Example");
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.setSize(150, 150);

        BordeRedondo border = new BordeRedondo(10); // radio = 10

        JButton addBtn = new JButton("X");
        addBtn.setBounds(10,10, 30, 30);
        addBtn.setBorder(border); // radio

        frame.add(addBtn);

        frame.setVisible(true);    

    }

}

class BordeRedondo implements Border {

    private int radio;  

    BordeRedondo(int radius) {
        this.radio = radius;
    }  

    public Insets getBorderInsets(Component c) {
        return new Insets(this.radio+1, this.radio+1, this.radio+2, this.radio);
    }  

    public boolean isBorderOpaque() {
        return true;
    }  

    public void paintBorder(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        g.drawRoundRect(x, y, width-1, height-1, radio, radio);
    }

  }
```

Comment: se ve el rectangulo del jbutton cardeol